# Vite development mode to include jQuery widgets/plugins

Tags: jquery, widget, vite, jquery-widgets

jQuery widgets work with `vite build`, but it do not work with `vite`. Then they are not available - `object.widgetFunction()` gives that `widgetFunction is not a function`.

Is there anyway to get them to work in development mode specifically to be able to use the automatic refresh from the laravel plugin? I am using the inject plugin already, but it does not seem to matter in development mode.

Comment: Can you share your `vite.config.js`?